# Включение доступности кнопки при закрытии TabPage - C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Когда нажимаю кнопку (button) открывается вкладка (tabPage) в tabControl и в этом случае кнопка (button) находится в статусе недоступна

```
button.Enabled = false
```

Подскажите, а как сделать, когда я закрываю вкладку (tabPage), то кнопка (button) должна снова включиться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void tabControlTablica_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // При нажатии закрыть вкладку
        for (int i = 0; i < tabControlTablica.TabPages.Count; i++)
        {
            Rectangle tab_rect = tabControlTablica.GetTabRect(i);
            RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(
                tab_rect.Left - 2 + tab_margin,
                tab_rect.Y + 2 + tab_margin,
                tab_rect.Width - 2 * tab_margin,
                tab_rect.Height - 2 * tab_margin);
            if (e.X >= rect.Right - Xwid &&
                e.X <= rect.Right &&
                e.Y >= rect.Top - 1 &&
                e.Y <= rect.Top + Xwid)
            {
                if (tabControlTablica.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    button1.Enabled = true;
                }
                if (tabControlTablica.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    button2.Enabled = true;
                }
                if (tabControlTablica.SelectedIndex == 2)
                {
                    button3.Enabled = true;
                }
                if (tabControlTablica.SelectedIndex == 3)
                {
                    button4.Enabled = true;
                }
                if (tabControlTablica.SelectedIndex == 4)
                {
                    button5.Enabled = true;
                }
                if (tabControlTablica.SelectedIndex == 5)
                {
                    button6.Enabled = true;
                }
               // tabControlTablica.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
                tabControlTablica.TabPages.Remove(tabControlTablica.TabPages[i]);
                tabControlTablica.SelectedIndex = tabControlTablica.TabPages.Count - 1;

            }
  }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(tabControlTablica.TabPages.IndexOf(tabPage1) < 0)
        {
            tabControlTablica.Controls.Add(tabPage1);
        }
        if(button1.Enabled == true)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControlTablica.TabPages.IndexOf(tabPage2) < 0)
        {
            tabControlTablica.Controls.Add(tabPage2);
        }
        if (button2.Enabled == true)
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControlTablica.TabPages.IndexOf(tabPage3) < 0)
        {
            tabControlTablica.Controls.Add(tabPage3);
        }
        if (button3.Enabled == true)
        {
            button3.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControlTablica.TabPages.IndexOf(tabPage4) < 0)
        {
            tabControlTablica.Controls.Add(tabPage4);
        }
        if (button4.Enabled == true)
        {
            button4.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControlTablica.TabPages.IndexOf(tabPage5) < 0)
        {
            tabControlTablica.Controls.Add(tabPage5);
        }
        if (button5.Enabled == true)
        {
            button5.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControlTablica.TabPages.IndexOf(tabPage6) < 0)
        {
            tabControlTablica.Controls.Add(tabPage6);
        }
          if (button6.Enabled == true)
        {
            button6.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну а где вы вкладку закрываете, там нельзя кнопку активировать?

Comment: покажите как вы переопределяете заголовок для TabPage, а лучше сразу дайте ссылку на источник

Comment: У меня почему-то не получилось активировать кнопку во вкладке tabControl.

Comment: Вот таким способом я выключил кнопку -                                      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(tabControlTablica.TabPages.IndexOf(tabPage1) < 0)
            {
                tabControlTablica.Controls.Add(tabPage1);
            }
            if(button1.Enabled == true)
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

Comment: Покажите код, который закрывает вкладку. Точнее внесите его в вопрос, под вопросом должна быть кнопка «править».

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < tabControlTablica.TabPages.Count; i++)
            {...} tabControlTablica.TabPages.Remove(tabControlTablica.TabPages[i]);
                    tabControlTablica.SelectedIndex = tabControlTablica.TabPages.Count - 1;
 Вот это отвечает за закрытие вкладки.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за подсказку,                                                               
for (int i = 0; i < tabControlTablica.TabPages.Count; i++) {...}                         
                     
 if (tabControlTablica.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        button1.Enabled = true;
                    }                                                                                      
  Вставил перед этим кодом
tabControlTablica.TabPages.Remove(tabControlTablica.TabPages‌​[i]); tabControlTablica.SelectedIndex = tabControlTablica.TabPages.Count - 1

Comment: Не всё получилось, когда вкладки закрываешь последовательно от последней к первой, то все кнопки становятся активные, а вот когда их хаотично закрываешь, то тогда не все кнопки становятся активные.      
       ;

Comment: Прошу прощения не дочитал Ваше сообщение - всё в комментарии коды пихаю.